# Sort a list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, absolute-value

I have this list

```
[1,-5,10,6,3,-4,-9]
```

But now I want the list to be sorted like this:

```
[10,-9,6,-5,-4,3,1]
```

As you can see I want to order from high to low no matter what sign each number has, but keeping the sign, is it clear?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `abs` as key to the `sorted` function or `list.sort`:

```
>>> lis = [1,-5,10,6,3,-4,-9]
>>> sorted(lis, key=abs, reverse=True)
[10, -9, 6, -5, -4, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 16):

Use:

```
    l.sort(key= abs, reverse = True)
```

Lists can be sorted using the sort() method. And the sort method has a parameter, called key, which you can pass a function. Using this parameter, your list won't be ordered by the values of the list, but by the values of your function on the list.

In your case, you should use the abs() function, which will return the absolute value of your list elements. So, your list

```
>>> l = [1,-5,10,6,3,-4,-9]
```

Will be sorted like it was

```
>>>  [abs(1),abs(-5),abs(10),abs(6),abs(3),abs(-4),abs(-9)]
```

Which should be:

```
>>> [1 ,-4 ,-5 ,6 ,-9 ,10]
```

To order from the biggest to the smalles, use the reverse=True parameter also.

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted([5, 2, 3, 1, 4])
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) for more details.

Comment: Try to run this with the given input list, and check whether the result really matches the expected one

Answer (score -1):

I'm providing code with output data:

```
example_list = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5]

example_list.sort()
print("Ascending ordered list: ", example_list)

example_list.sort(reverse=True)
print("Descending ordered list: ", example_list)
```

Output:

```
Ascending order: [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 9]
Descending order: [9, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: This hardly contributes anything new relative to the older answers, and misses the crucial requirement to ignore signs.

Comment: Again, it does not cope correctly with negative numbers as required in the question; and anyway, it only repeats things which have been explained in previous answers.