# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

At work we recently upgraded to pandas 0.20 and I have a list of numbers that I sort using sort (however this is no longer supported and I am getting the above message when I try `sort_values`).

```
numbers = [1, 3, 4, 2] 
numbers.sort(reverse = True) 
print numbers

[4, 3, 2, 1]

numbers.sort_values(reverse = True)
```

I'm getting this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Comment: try :  `pd.Series(numbers).sort_values()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199984/sort-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

You don't appear to be using pandas at all here; `numbers` is a standard Python list. And the method to sort a list is just called `sort`.

```
numbers.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: cheers, I'm still a novice at this and I used this example without understanding numbers was a standard python list.

so I guess if I called the list of number "list" and reran it then I get the same error

>>> lst = [1, 3, 4, 2] 
>>> lst.sort_values(reverse = True) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sort_values'
>>>

Answer (score 4):

Use `sorted()`:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
new_lst = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
```

Comment: thanks, that however only prints out the lst in the order required and doesn't store it as required

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using sort() rather than sort(reverse = True) and it worked as I wanted, thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.