# Django AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, django-celery

I'm getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sort_values'` in below code,

task.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import,unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task
from time import sleep
import eda
import os

@shared_task
def aync_task(amz_columns_dict, download_path, file_name, data):
    sleep(10)
    eda_object = eda.eda(col_dict=amz_columns_dict)
    save_path = download_path
    name_of_file = file_name 
    file_path = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".html")     
    eda_object.create_report(data=data, filename=file_path)
    return 'task complete'
```

views.py :

```
def eda_flow(request):
    path = '/Unilever/satyajit/us_amz.csv'
    mode = 'rb'
    df = pd.read_csv("/home/satyajit/Desktop/opensource/data/us_amz.csv", low_memory=False)
    df = df.head(100)
    json_records = df.reset_index().to_json(orient ='records')
    data = []
    data = json.loads(json_records)
    context = {'data': data, 'message': 'data loaded successfully.'}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id_col = request.POST.get('id_col')
        file_name = request.POST.get('file_name')
        download_path = request.POST.get('download_path')
        amz_columns_dict = {'id_col': id_col}
        try:   
            if os.path.exists(download_path):
                status = aync_task.delay(amz_columns_dict, download_path, file_name, data)
                return render(request,'home/index.html', {'message': 'Save Complete'})
            else:
                return render(request,'home/index.html', {'message': 'download path is not exist'})
        except Exception as e:
            print('error is---->', e)
            return render(request,'home/index.html', {'message': 'Error while generating EDA'})
    return render(request, "home/tables-simple.html", context)
```

The error of this code on below as screenshot:

[image]

I've also tried to search similar question here ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220128/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-sort-values)) but that does not helpful to me.

Any help would be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done, `import pandas as pd` then `data = pd.DataFrame(data)` to convert the python list to a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: @raphael yes, i have done that

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` variable that is being passed to the `async_task` method is being set using `data = json.loads(json_records)` so it's a normal Python list. You must convert this to a Pandas dataframe before using it with `eda_object.create_report`.

Comment: After i convert it to pandas dataframe then i'm getting this error `Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 0):

this solved my issue:

task.py :

```
@shared_task
def aync_task(amz_columns_dict, download_path, file_name):
    sleep(10)
    df = pd.read_csv("/home/satyajit/Desktop/opensource/data/us_amz.csv", low_memory=False)
    df = df.head(3500)
    eda_object = eda.eda(col_dict=amz_columns_dict)
    save_path = download_path
    name_of_file = file_name
    # file_path = Path(save_path, name_of_file+".html")  
    file_path = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".html")     
    eda_object.create_report(data=df, filename=file_path)
    return 'task complete'
```