# Python: Considering a list comprising of multiple occurrences of only two possible values. How do I "push/compress" all of one value to the left

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have been studying different ways of manipulating lists for awhile now and I have encountered a problem that my inexperienced self cannot seem to solve.

Consider the list `a = [1,0,1,0,1,1,0]`.

I want to push all occurrences of `1`s to the left making the list `a = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0]`.

Is there some function out there I could call that I am not aware of, or do I have to do this manually? I want to iterate through the list one by one but I feel like it wouldn't be efficient.

Comment: Isn't this just sorting the list? In this case, sort in reverse order.`a.sort(reverse=True)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199984/sort-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
a.sort(key=lambda x:x!=1)
```

Change 1 to any other value you want to move.

Comment: Is there a way to move the 1's n amount of times starting from the right? E.g. a = [1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1] to a = [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0] with n = 2?

Comment: You can do some game with slicing like `a[-2:] + a[:-2]` in this case

Answer (score 0):

Since sorting is a good solution in this case, it's not working in general. If your list contains more elements than just `0` and `1`, you would like to concatenate all `1`s found with a new list that is formed after elimination of these `1`s like so:

```
result = [1]*a.count(1)+list(filter(lambda x: x!=1, a))
```

Output for `a = [1,2,3,5,2,1,1,4]` is `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4]` then.