# How can i use the sort function if i want to sort ascending by a criterion and descending by another criterion?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, key

I am trying to implement the A* algorithm in Python as a learning exercise. I have a list of nodes, called `open`, that contains strings that represent the names of graph nodes. Example: `open["node_a", "node_b", "node_c"]`. I also have two `defaultdict` dictionaries, `f_estim` and `g`, that contain values like `{"name_of_node" : integer_representing_a_certain_cost_associated_to_the_node}`. I am required to sort the `open` list ascending by the value associated in `f_estim`, and if that value is equal for two nodes, descending according to the value in `g`. I am sorting ascending like so: `open.sort(key=lambda node: f_estim[node])`. How can i also sort descending when reaching two equal values? I could not find the answer in the documentation of the `sort` function. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried sorted funtion [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199984/sort-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Please add full examples (input and expected output)

Comment: Your lambda can return a tuple with primary criterion first and negative of secondary criterion second.

Comment: Have you tried doing something like this ?
open.sort(key=lambda node: (f_estim[node], -g[node))

Comment: Examples:

open ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
f_estim {"a" : 5, "b" : 5, "c" : 4, " d" : 4}
g: {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3, " d" : 4}

after open.sort(???), i want to obtain open["d", "c", "b", "a"]

Comment: The tuple suggestion is the solution to my problem. Thank you very much everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
open.sort(key=lambda node: (f_estim[node], -g[node]))
```

Comment: Note that this will only work for ordering criteria that are numeric, and not for other types of comparable criteria (e.g. strings)