# How to sort a list in Python?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of numbers in Python and I’m trying to sort them in ascending order. Here’s my code:

```
numbers = [5, 2, 1, 8, 4]
```

I tried using the sort() function like this: `sort(numbers)`, but I get an error that says name 'sort' is not defined. What am I doing wrong and how can I sort my list?

Comment: `numbers.sort()`

Comment: You may want to familiarize yourself with the Python documentation. The function is called [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). Alternatively, you could use the `sort` method of the list. Read the documentation to find out about the difference between those two approaches.

Comment: You should look up the difference between functions and methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199984/sort-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you ask a question try to be as descriptive as possible regarding your problem. A part from the input you are using, here you should add the whole code and also the error message if possible.

Okay!, let's go to the question. Note that [sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is a method of the `list` class, and it affects the original list you are calling this method on, because it runs in-place (aka returns `None`). Therefore the syntax (without any additional arguments) would be:

```
numbers.sort()
```

This approach is slightly more efficient.

On the other side, if you want to use the built-in function [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), you need to assign it to a new variable, as this function creates a new list from the original one, for example:

```
numbers_sorted = sorted(numbers)
```

Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto) for more examples.

Hope it is clear enough!